# Javascript Textbox value returning object error

Tags: javascript, string, object, textbox

I've been working with a simple form to calculate a total amount of money for an order someone would place. I'm using a pre-set framework for the form, which uses input texts for the quantitiy of an item.

For some reason, when I access the value, convert it to a string, and then call it's length, I receive the error "SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'length'". When I did a console.log() on the typeof the value, I did get a string.

Why am I receiving this error?

If it isn't clear, I'm only looking for a solution to this error, not code critique.

Console text:
LOG: a, small: 2 
LOG: textVal: 2 
LOG: type of textVal: string 
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'length' 
Line 130

```
function numOnly(a){//used to check that only a number has been inputted into the quantity box
var textVal = document.getElementById(a).value.toString();
console.log("textVal: "+textVal);
console.log("type of textVal: "+typeof textVal);
var returnVal = '';
for(var i = 0;i<textVal.length();i++){
    if(textVal.charAt(i)=='0'||textVal.charAt(i)=='1'||textVal.charAt(i)=='2'||textVal.charAt(i)=='3'||textVal.charAt(i)=='4'||textVal.charAt(i)=='5'||textVal.charAt(i)=='6'||textVal.charAt(i)=='7'||textVal.charAt(i)=='8'||textVal.charAt(i)=='9'){
        returnVal+=textVal.charAt(i);
    }//if
}//for
console.log("a after loop: "+a);
return returnVal;
function numOnly(a){//used to check that only a number has been inputted into the quantity box WHY DOES IT GET AN OBJECT WINDOW
var textVal = '';
textVal = document.getElementById(a).value.toString();
console.log("textVal: "+textVal);
console.log("type of textVal: "+typeof textVal);
var returnVal = '';
for(var i = 0;i<textVal.length();i++){
    if(textVal.charAt(i)=='0'||textVal.charAt(i)=='1'||textVal.charAt(i)=='2'||textVal.charAt(i)=='3'||textVal.charAt(i)=='4'||textVal.charAt(i)=='5'||textVal.charAt(i)=='6'||textVal.charAt(i)=='7'||textVal.charAt(i)=='8'||textVal.charAt(i)=='9'){
        returnVal+=textVal.charAt(i);
    }//if
}//for
console.log("a after loop: "+a);
return returnVal;
}//numOnly()
```

where i'm calling the function

```
case "S":
a=document.getElementById(sizeId[i]);
console.log("a, small: "+a.value);
if(a!=null) SSTotal+=(parseInt(numOnly(sizeId[i]))*prices[1]);
break;
```

Comment: length is property not method, and value from html elements is already string so toString is useless, and instead of charAt you can use bracket notation ... textVal[i] === "0"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Length is a property not a method so try:

```
textVal.length
```

instead of

```
textVal.length()
```

Also you dont need to do a `toString()` on the value. it will be string by itself.